# Remove everything between specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I read a file with javascript and this file contains a lot of begin and end statement like below
, and my purpose is to remove every thing that exists between these begin and end statement?

```
//<BEGIN>

sample string

//</END>

another string

//<BEGIN>

another string

//</END>
```

Comment: Do u want to remove the contents in <replace> tag??

Comment: With DOM manipulation, not regex. Now, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear enough and therefore I edited again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hold text inside the tags:

```
var res = string.match(/<BEGIN>([\s\S]*?)<\/END>/g);
```

To remove text inside the tags:

```
var res = string.replace(/([\s\S]*?)<BEGIN>[\s\S]*?<\/END>/g, '$1');
```

To remove text outside the tags:

```
var res = string.replace(/<BEGIN>[\s\S]*?<\/END>/g, '');
```

Comment: thanks if I want to do vice versa means hold every thing between begin and end and remove others, what should I do?

Answer (score -2):

Assuming replace is a class you can try this Jquery:

```
<script>        
 $( " " ).replaceAll( ".replace" );
 </script>
```